# How to shift density?

Tags: r, probability-density

I am trying to "correct" the results of the model with the insitu data.
I measure the tempreture at a point and I look at the same point the model output.

I have two data frames, one for insitu data and another for model data.
Here is an exemple of 2 densities, and I want to shift the model density to insitu density. 
Is it possible to do that?

```
insitu <- data.frame(Temp = rnorm(500, 6, 2))
model <- data.frame(Temp = rnorm(500, 7, 2.5))
insitu$mesure <- "insitu"
model$mesure <- "model"
allData <- rbind(insitu, model)
ggplot(allData, aes(Temp, fill=mesure)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
```

Comment: You can scale it by multiplying and you can translate it by adding. Since your model mean is 7 and your insitu mean is 6, you can subtract 1 from all the model values to shift it down to have the same mean. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean this:

```
ggplot(allData, aes(Temp, fill=mesure)) + geom_density(position = "stack", alpha = 0.2)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `stack` seems misleading... `position = 'identity'` would allow a comparison

Comment: @Gregor: I think the whole concept is misleading..Anyway, the "identity" is the default value, so it will have no effect to the result.

Comment: You're right, you could leave out the position to use the default `identity` - it will be different than stacking them on top of each other and adding their y values together as you have now.

Comment: @Gregor:Yes, but if I leave out the position, then it is just what the poster has already.I am not sure what the poster wants, I think he wants something like that.I am not saying that this is "correct" but I can't know the logic behind shifting the plot.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, since OP doesn't mention "plot" or "graph" at all in the question I assumed they were asking about a data transformation, not for plotting help.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about a data transformation. I would like to compute the model distribution equalization acording to the parametrs  given by insitu distribution.

Comment: @Tali:You can check Gregor's answer then.